# NDsolve memory leak

Tags: differential-equations, memory

Every time I run `NDsolve` it uses some memory that I am not able to free later.

The following is an example code based on the spring equation (Hooke's law) that increases memory usage by 280 bytes each iteration.

---

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
tlimit = 1;
x0 = 1;
m = 1;
k = 1;

Do[
  memory1 = MemoryInUse[];
  Print[memory1];
  sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -k/m*x[t], x[0] == x0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0., tlimit}];
  Clear[sol];
  ClearSystemCache[];
  memory2 = MemoryInUse[];
  Print[memory2];
 , {x0, {0, 1, 2, 3}}]

memory2 - memory1
```

---

As you can see I have already tried with  `$HistoryLenght = 0, ClearSystemCache[], Clear[sol]`

Does anyone know how to free that memory again so that the memory usage will not increase at every iteration?

Comment: Just asked a related question, if not duplicate, but with two MWE with different outcomes: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116401/ndsolve-memory-leak.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! Hope someone can shed some light into it.

Comment: I was quite surprised you did not have any answer. I plan to give a bounty if I don't have an answer within two days. Here the correct link to the question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119501/memory-leak-with-ndsolve

Comment: Mike, you should report that to WRI.